# When to use [in] vs [in,out] with struct params in Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

Would the following be an example of an [in] or an [in,out] parameter in Doxygen? I have a pointer to a struct that I am passing to a function. The function will modify a piece of the struct but not all of it.

Additionally, what if I return the same struct pointer to enable me to do function chaining? In this case I am still modifying a piece of the input parameter but I am also returning it.

Comment: Your latter description would seem to indicate in, out *and* a function retval.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a case of `[in,out]`. You take the `struct` (via pointer) and after the function returns the `struct` is no longer the same as before. The fact that you don't modify all of it and that it remains in the same location is irrelevant. If your function has a side-effect that modifies an object, it is an out-parameter.

The fact that you return the pointer to the object has no effect on the fact that the object you accept as argument is modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
const struct bla *x
```

is a `[in]` parameter

```
struct bla *x
```

is a `[in,out]` parameter